# Is there any easy way to delete unnecessary vertices/trianlges?

Tags: optimization, polycount

In this example, there is a lot of unnecessary triangles and vertices, is there any magic tool that can delete them?
[image: an example]

Comment: you could try faces command "tris to quads" (alt-j)

Comment: You could try using the dissolve tools

Comment: as for what @WhatAMesh  suggest, select unwanted edges and use "limited dissolve"